# How can I verify Firebase Installation ID-Token on the server

Tags: firebase, server

we are using Firebase Installation to create a create unique Id for each Android device. However, we need to verify each ID-Token sent by the user to server. Is there any firebase SDK or API that verify that ID-Token pair?

Comment: Check this please https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations

Comment: I have the same question, and this does not seem to be documented. Decoding the tokens is straightforward using a JWT library (and you can try it e.g. at https://jwt.io), but verifying them I think would require the public/private key used to generate them. @Khaled this link explains how to _generate_ the tokens, but not how to _verify_ them.